# Shiny App Error: /v1/applications/ 400 - Validation Error Execution halted

Tags: r, deployment, server, shiny, publish

Hi I'm having a million problems trying to publish my app to shiny.io.

Firstly, I have Rtools 3.2 installed in my computer and set to the Path, but it is not recognized in the registry. Nevermind, this code should fix it:

```
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
install.Rtools(choose_version = FALSE, check = TRUE, use_GUI = TRUE,
page_with_download_url = "http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, keep_install_file=TRUE")
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
```

Next, to deploy my app to my shiny.io account:

```
library(shinyapps)
shinyapps::setAccountInfo(name='xxxx', token='xxxxxxxxxx', secret='xxxxxxxx')
```

Then my app starts running in a browser, and I click publish to my shiny account. However, when the app is being deployed, it shows the following error:

```
Preparing to deploy application...Error: /v1/applications/ 400 - Validation Error
Execution halted
```

Any ideas what the problems may be? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same error returned. In my case the problem was the name of the app itself. Deployed apps must have names at least 4 characters long with no spaces.

Answer (score 7):

Setting an application name solved this problem for me. My application directory contained a space.

```
deployApp(appName = "myapp")
```

Comment: Passing an `appName` solved to problem for me as well. Path wasn't sufficient even though I never use spaces in file or directory names.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, however, my app name was fine and even adding 'appName =' did not help. Just a side note that this issue came up because I changed the name of my folder in effort to change the name of my app in shinyapp.io

The only thing that worked for me is publishing through the "Publish" button of Rstudio on upper right. I would recommend publishing using that instead of command. You can select files you do not want to publish within the App folder and you can publish the app under a different name then your local name.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar errors and the issue was resolved after I changed the name of the directory that holds the "app.R" file from only 3 characters to more than 4 characters.